# Compile custom JSP tag handler

Tags: java, jsp, compilation, custom-tags, tag-handler

```
package com.mytag.tags;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;

public class MyTagHandler extends SimpleTagSupport{

public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    JspWriter out=pageContext.getOut();
    try{
        out.print(new java.util.Date());
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    return SKIP_BODY;
    }

}
```

Need to compile this custom JSP tag handler without use of any IDE.
Can anyone please mention how to compile it i tried *javac -cp "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\jst
l2\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar;" MyTagHandler.java*
It's not Working

Comment: try this: `javac -classpath javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar TagHandler.java`

Comment: @AjayKulkarni thanks for replying i did exactly the same .

Comment: Did it work? Your command was `javac -cp "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\jst l2\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar;" `, I don't see `.java` file in your command

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Its not working

Comment: @AjayKulkarni java file is there its in the next line bro

Comment: @AjayKulkarni  javac -cp "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\jst l2\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar;" MyTagHandler.java

Comment: Why don't you add that library and your .java file in the same directory and try out without double quotations?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Its not working still i tried _C:\Users\dell\Desktop\jstl2\WEB-INF\classes>javac -cp javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2
.1.jar MyTagHandler.java_

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: 8 errors bro MyTagHandler.java:5: error: package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
                        ^
MyTagHandler.java:6: error: package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
                        ^
MyTagHandler.java:5: error: package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
                        ^
MyTagHandler.java:6: error: package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
                        ^
@AjayKulkarni

Comment: Oh... add that `javax.servlet.jsp` in same folder and try again. You are using `import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;`, but there is no supporting library for that

Comment: @AjayKulkarni you mean i should import javax.servlet.jsp.*; is that?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni can you edit my code its still not working

Comment: Download jar file from this link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxservletjar.htm,, add it to the same directory and compile again

Answer (score 1):

This code is not JSTL at all. This code is a custom JSP taghandler. JSTL are those tags which you import in JSP via `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/*` namespace URI, such as [`<c:xxx>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html), [`<fmt:xxx>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html), etc. JSTL does not represent "custom JSP taghandlers". To learn more about what exactly JSTL is, head to [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

As to your concrete problem, you just need to have JSP API in the runtime classpath. This should already be hinted by the package names of the imports: `javax.servlet.jsp.*`. You don't have imported `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.*` anywhere, so the JSTL API JAR file is unnecessary.

You normally find the JSP API JAR file in the library/module folder of the target server. The fact that you manually placed JSTL in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder suggests that you're not targeting a real Java EE server such as WildFly, TomEE, etc, but a barebones servletcontainer such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org). I'll therefore assume Tomcat as an example. You can find the JSP API in the `/lib` folder of Tomcat installation.

Assuming Tomcat is installed (unzipped) in `C:\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.33`, here's the correct command to compile the custom JSP taghandler:

```
javac -cp "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\lib\jsp-api.jar" com/mytag/tags/MyTagHandler.java
```

Note that this will pop out "cannot find symbol" compilation error, but that part is completely unrelated to the question currently asked. In order to solve the new compilation error, head to [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)